# How do I make an image that is currently hidden, become visible upon validation passing in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a simple web form in asp.net that has some validation on the form fields. I also have an image whose visibility is set to false. In my validation if statement I want code that will make that image visible if the validation has passed. Below is what I have but the image is not displaying. Thanks!

```
if (!Page.IsValid) return;

      //Order is valid. Process it.
      lblOrderDetails.Text = "<h1>Success!</h1>" +
          "<b>Email: </b> " + tbEmail.Text + "<br />" +
          "<b>Model: </b> " + dlModel.SelectedItem.Text + "<br />" +
          "<b>Discounts: </b> ";

      imgSnowboard.Visible = true;



<asp:Image Visible="false" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/SnowBoard.jpg" ID="imgSnowboard"/>
```

Comment: What have you tried?  Is the visible = true line being hit?  What does the HTML look like?

Comment: Are you sure that visibility of the parent control of your Image is not set to False?

Answer (score 0):

Two things, first unrelated to the question, I would start using `string.Format` as opposed to concatenating like that.  It's just cleaner, and easier to manage.  Ex.

```
lblOrderDetails.Text = string.Format("<h1>Success!</h1>
    + "<b>Email: </b>{0}<br />" 
    + "<b>Model: </b>{1}<br />" 
    + "<b>Discounts: </b> ", tbEmail.Text, dlModel.SelectedItem.Text);
```

Instead of the mess of + signs, this simplifies it a little more.

As to your question, I would say remove the `Visible="false"` property from the declaration, and instead, call out the image on PageLoad and set the visible property to false server side.  `Visible"false"` can be kind of funky when you have a control declared with it.  It almost acts like it doesn't create the control, and the C# has trouble accessing it, so it may be trying to show that image, but it literally cannot find it.

Hope this helps!